# Adding nodes into a pointer and creating a list which you then use to print polynomials

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to make a program which prints polynomials in this format, 2x^7 + 1x^2 + 6x^8. I'm using stdarg.h to pass arguments into individual nodes which then pass it into a struct pointer. Eventually Im to use a print function that will print out the nodes in the struct pointer they originally went to. Note the poly create function the first number is the number of terms thatll be in the polynomial and then it prints the polynomials back to front which means when i print it i should expect 1x^7 + 7x^5 + 3x^2 + 3x^4. However when i try to print it out im able to print the first node since it passed but when i attempted to use a for loop to print the rest it gave me an error. I hope my explantion wasnt too bad I tried my best but please ask if i need to clarify something.

code for .h

```
typedef struct nodeT{
  int coef;
  int powr;
  struct nodeT *next;
} node;

typedef struct {
   int num_terms;
   node *terms;
} poly;

void poly_print(poly *P) ; //
poly *poly_create(int num,...) ;
```

This is my code in my .c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "poly_ADT.h"

int main(){
    poly *P0;
    P0 = poly_create(4,3,4,3,2,7,5,1,7); 
    printf("P0: ");
    poly_print(P0);

}

poly *poly_create(int num, ...){
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, num);
    poly *p = malloc(sizeof(poly));
    p->num_terms = num;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        node *temp = (node* )malloc(sizeof(node* ));
        temp->coef = va_arg(arguments, int);
        temp->powr = va_arg(arguments, int);
        p->terms = temp;
    }
    va_end(arguments);
    return p;
}

void poly_print(poly *P) {
    int x = 0;
    node *n = P->terms;
    //printf("%i terms: ", P->num_terms);
    int i;
    printf("%ix^%i", n->coef, n->powr);
    if (n->next) printf(" + ");

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `p->terms = temp;` It is simply overwritten, but there is a need to link list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
poly *poly_create(int num, ...){
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, num);
    poly *p = malloc(sizeof(poly));
    p->num_terms = num;
    p->terms = NULL;//! add
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        node *temp = (node* )malloc(sizeof(node* ));
        temp->coef = va_arg(arguments, int);
        temp->powr = va_arg(arguments, int);
        temp->next = p->terms;//! add
        p->terms = temp;
    }
    va_end(arguments);
    return p;
}

void poly_print(poly *P) {
    int x = 0;
    node *n = P->terms;
    int i;
    while(n){
        printf("%ix^%i", n->coef, n->powr);
        if (n = n->next) printf(" + ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```